# Finding function from the power series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{3^{n-1}}{4^n \cdot n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I have to find sum of series $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{3^{n-1}}{4^n \cdot n}$$

The hint is to find a function whose power series at some point is equal to the given series.

I am struggling with finding such a function.

One the one hand I have

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(x_0)}{n!}(x-x_0)^n$$

And on the other hand I have series in this form

$$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_n(x-x_0)^n$$

How do I find such $f(x)$ and point $x_0$ from the equations above?

Would be grateful for any hints.

Comment: It may help if you re-write the series in the form $\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{n}\left( {\frac{3}{4}} \right)^n }$. (Or even $ - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^{n + 1} }}{n}\left( { - \frac{3}{4}} \right)^n }$.)

Comment: Just be sure the answer is $\frac{2\ln(2)}{3}$? Because I have found the function $\ln(1+x)$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.